Is there a way to call a external script with an event
I'm working on a script, and I'm wondering, can I call a External script, such as <script src='example.com'></script> but with an event, so onload='[run external script]' with a one-liner? This is what I'm currently working on
<img src='/HelloWorld' onerror='[run code on external web]'></img>

I'm working with a longer script, and I don't want to use event listeners. and I would prefer little, to no other code.
edit
I dont know what i should try out.

What do you mean by "external script"? You can use AJAX to send a request to the server.

"I don't want to use event listeners" What do you think onerror is?

Have you looked up any examples of how to run JavaScript code from an onerror handler like this?  (Or onclick or any other on* attribute?)  You indicate that you haven't tried anything, but haven't specified what prevents you from trying anything.  For the code shown, where did you even find an example of using onerror which didn't include an example of how it's used?  What actual problem have you encountered here?

Well, yes.  When you do <script src='example.com'></script>, that runs all the code in the script.  So, if that file contains a function, that function is available to your page as if the function had been defined locally.
So, given file http://example.com/myfile.js containing:
function myerror()
{
    alert("Error occurred!");
}

You can write:
<script src="http://example.com/myfile.js"></script>
...
<img src='HellowWorld', onerror='myerror();'>


Nothing about cross origin concerns?

@HereticMonkey CORS doesn't affect script tags, only AJAX. That's how JSONP is used to get around CORS.

@Barmar I didn't mention CORS. I was thinking about XSS and other security concerns (not to mention privacy) which appear to be glossed over completely in this answer.

@HereticMonkey What part of this is cross-origin? I assume example.com represents the domain of the website.

@Barmar The whole point of the question is "calling an external script", so I assumed example.com represents a domain other than the one being built... I could be wrong, but that's how I interpreted it.

I never really understood what they meant by "external script" (see my first comment). But in general, if you load a third-party JavaScript, you're trusting them very much.
